# Android Chronometer Widget lags against other watches

Tags: android, time, lag, chronometer

I have created a simple activity with a chronometer widget just to display the elapsed time.
The code is really simple:

```
//Initiate the chronometer base time
chChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
//start the chronometer
chChronometer.start();
```

The time displayed lags hard against other chronometers, what can be visible within less than one minute. 
The device I´m testing on is a Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.2
My references for comparison are a Nexus 7 running 4.2 (standard stopwatch, not an app), 2 real watches

Is this a known issue? Are there any other steps I should take to make things go right?

Thanks,
Gabriel Simões

Comment: Have you tried using `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead, for comparison's sake?

Comment: The reference in the parameter setBase is just to define the exact time when the chronometer started. The Android documentation states that elapsedRealtime() should be used. Even if currentTimeMillis could be used, the problem lays in the time passing: each second lags some milliseconds and this happened in 3 different devices using the same implementation. Also the comparison against Android 4.2 stopwatch displayed the same results: Chronometer lags behind